# Linear algebra libraries and dynamic parallelism in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

With the advent of dynamic parallelism in 3.5 and above CUDA architectures, is it possible to call linear algebra libraries from within `__device__` functions?

Can the CUSOLVER library in CUDA 7 be called from a kernel (`__global__`) function?

Comment: The one word answer is no. These libraries have excellent documentation, you could try reading them.

Comment: I just wanted to be sure of the answer. I used a C code to perform eigenvalues decomposition of several small matrices..each thread performs the decomposition of a matrix..but it was very slow (10 ms) I'm looking for a way to accelerate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CUBLAS library functions can be [called from device code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#device-api).

Thrust *algorithms* can be [called from device code](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/power-cpp11-cuda-7/).

Various CURAND functions can be [called from device code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/device-api-overview.html#device-api-overview).

Other libraries that are part of the CUDA toolkit at this time (i.e. CUDA 7)  -- CUFFT, CUSPARSE, CUSOLVER -- can only be used from host code.